# The most efficient way to sum all possible pairs (x_ik, y_j) for a given k?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, algorithm, numpy

I have two numpy array `x` with shape `(n,m)` and `y` with shape `(p,)`.
I would like to sum all possible pairs `x[k, i]` and `y[j]` to create a new numpy array `z` with shape `(n, m*p)`.

A naïve algorithm would be :

```py
import numpy as np
# some code
z = np.empty((n, m*p))
for k in range(n):
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(p):
            z[k, i + m * j] = x[k, i] + y[j]
```

This algorithm has a polynomial complexity : `O(n*m*p)`
Knowing I am working on array with $n ~ 1e6$ I am looking a for a more efficient algorithm using the power of numpy and/or pandas.

I have done some research and I found a possible solution :
[Efficient way to sum all possible pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498920/efficient-way-to-sum-all-possible-pairs)

But it does not fit with my specific problem, I mean I can use it but it will still not be pythonic as I would iterate with one loop (the solution is reusable without much effort for n=1).

Comment: `(x[:,None,:]+y[None,:,None]).reshape(x.shape[0],-1)`.  In effect an outer sum of the 2 arrays with some reshaping.  Before the reshape `z` is (k,p,m)

Comment: Would you like to give an explanation of your answer ? Is it more efficient than `O(n*m*p)` ?

Comment: You could add `sleep(1000)` to the inside of your third loop and it would still be `O(n*m*p)`. Algorithm complexity is not the only thing determining how fast something's gonna run, mate.

Comment: Sure. But it remains a good metric to evaluate the speed of the program in my specific case, i.e. with $n$ very huge.

Comment: Your problem is exactly `O(n*m*p)`, you can't get better than that since you are creating `n*m*p` new values. The solution suggested by @hpaulj  utilizes compiled (vectorized) C code so it is a lot faster than vanilla python loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, not improving on the complexity but making use of vectorization and memory contiguity:

```py
np.add.outer(X,y).reshape(len(X), -1)
```